# Oracle Data Pump import to a sql file error :ORA-31655 no data or metadata objects

Tags: oracle, import, datapump

I'm using Data Pump to export/import data, one requirement is to import data to a sql file. The OS is window.
I made the follow export :

```
expdp system/password directory=dpump_dir dumpfile=tablesdump.dmp content=DATA_ONLY tables=user.tablename
```

and it works, I can see the file TABLESDUMP.DMP in the directory path.

then when I tried to import it to a sql file:

```
impdp system/password directory=dpump_dir dumpfile=tablesdump.dmp sqlfile=tables_export.sql
```

the log show :

```
.....
ORA-31655 no data or metadata objects selected for job
.....
```

and the sql file is created empty in the directory path.

I'm not DBA, I'm a Java developer , Can you help me?

Thks

Answer (score 2):

Since I exported the data using the parameter 'content=data_only' the dump file has not metadata info to be imported.  I tried export with 'content=all' parameter and then import to sql file worked.
I hope this be helpful for other cases.

Thanks to Anurag Tibrewa.